# Can't add log4net config transformation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, log4net, transformation

I am using VS 2012 Premium and can't see Add Config Transformation button for log4net configurations, Copy/Paste doesn't work as well. That's pretty strange as web.config transformations can be added without any problems.

[image]

I've tried standard actions like cleaning solution, cleaning git etc. but looks like the issue is somewhere else. Could you please assist if you faced the same trouble?

Comment: Config Transformations are not supported for third party config files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the problem by re-installing Configuration Transform extension with 2.1 version